# HtmltoCanvas Failed to execute Tainted canvases may not be exported Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

Throws error when setting a background image. Firefox working perfect but not in chrome

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable

    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         });
    });

    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream;");
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
    });

});
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: Just I want to download div content as an image on click button.